# Можно ли открывать в браузере сайт которые запустил на виртуалке?

Tags: php, laravel, debian, kvm, qemu

Есть Debian 10 на виртуалке в qemu kvm, туда я поставил php, laravel, nginx. Создал проект на laravel. Запустил его на 127.0.0.1:8000. Всё нормально работает, но как сделать что бы проект который я запустил в виртуалке, отображался в браузере на хостовой ОС.

Comment: Копать в эту сторону: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DtLEmqaOxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 потому и называется локальная петля, потому что виден только процессам на локальном хосте. Во первых, вам порт nginx надо прибиндить не к 127.0.0.1, а к 0.0.0.0 или адресу сетевого интерфейса виртуалки. Во вторых, как у вас организована сеть в kvm(NAT, bridge)? После того как привяжете порт .nginx к нормальному адресу, попробуйте по этому адресу обратиться.

Comment: Подключаюсь через virt-manager с помощью libvirt. Сеть организована с помощью NAT. Я так понимаю нужно изменить на сетевой мост?

Comment: @Ivan Да, вы верно понимаете. В вашем случае сетевой мост предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 0):

Создать сетевой интерфейс- к примеру самое простое мост, назначить ip адреса с обоих сторон. Настроить приложение не на 127.0.0.1:8000 а на тот самый ip  на мосте.